# Express 1d masked array as list of slices

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I have a 1d numpy array with booleans values (`mask`) which I would like to convert into a list of slices where the mask is True, e.g.:

```
mask = [False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

and I would like to obtain

```
[slice(1, 4, None), slice(6, 8, None)]
```

The numpy masked array operations (in particular `np.ma.clump_masked()`) can do that, but the only way I found to use it would be to do the following:

```
np.ma.clump_masked(np.ma.masked_array(np.ones_like(mask), mask))
```

which yields exactly what I'm looking for:

> [slice(1, 4, None), slice(6, 8, None)]

i.e., generating an array with the same shape as `mask`, applying the mask to it, and then computing `mask_clumped()` on that.

However, the `np.ma.masked_array(np.ones_like(mask), mask)`-step seems unnecessary to me. Is there any way to obtain the list of slices from a simplified operation which I would imagine to look like the following?

```
np.ma.clump_masked(mask)
```

Comment: You're right, I should have used
```np.ma.masked_array()``` instead. Thanks for letting me know, fixed it.

Comment: I think you can only shorten `np.ma.masked_array(mask, mask)` since you need a masked array. Your question contains a very useful approach to converting a boolean array to slices that I didn't know about before.

Comment: Good point that I don't have to generate a new array with ```np.ones_like()``` but I can simply take ```mask``` instead. But I still wonder why there is nothing like ```clump_masked()``` simply taking a mask...

Comment: Well, using ```np.ma.extras._ezclump(np.array(mask))``` would work, but it's not public

Comment: I have rarely seen anyone use it. It's [implemented](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/ma/extras.py#L1762-L1788) in python if you want to see how it works.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny please hit the “y” key on your keyboard before sharing a GitHub link. It’ll change the URL so your link keeps working longer than until the next commit. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4dc749edc3abacc7d6b59959fba43d23572206e1/numpy/ma/extras.py#L1972-L1998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.ma.masked_array` requires a masked array as input, not an `ndarray`. One approach is to do what you're currently doing and create a masked array

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.asarray([False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True])
masked_array = np.ma.masked_array(data=mask, mask=mask)
np.ma.clump_masked(masked_array)
```

However, I assume you're generating `mask` based on some condition? In which case, you can use [`np.ma.masked_where`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html). For example, to get all the slices of each even number from 0 to 9:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10)
masked_arr = np.ma.masked_where(arr % 2 == 0, arr)
np.ma.clump_masked(masked_arr)
```

which outputs:

```
[slice(0, 1, None),
 slice(2, 3, None),
 slice(4, 5, None),
 slice(6, 7, None),
 slice(8, 9, None)]
```

There are other functions such as `np.ma.masked_inside` which will create a masked array and mask all elements within some interval. Check the 'see also' of the `masked_where` docs for a list of the related funcitons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
As far as I can see [MaskedArray](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.22.0/numpy/ma/core.py#L2703-L6224) requires an array_like as data and a sequence for mask, so your proposed solution would work (but still takes the detour via creating an array which will never be used, except for its mask). Circumventing that seems to be possible by using ```np.ma.extras._ezclump()```.

I don't have a trivial condition (performing a permutation cluster test) which returns the mask, but thanks for the hint concerning ```masked_where()```